# DKIM Signing not working, amavisd indicates that is passes

Tags: ubuntu, email, dkim, email-server

amavisd-new testkeys indicates a pass, but mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com says that my DKIM signature could not be found?  Anyone ran into this before?  Anyone got any easy ways to set up DKIM signing?

Thanks

```
[redacted]@claygarland:/etc/amavis/conf.d# amavisd-new testkeys
TESTING#1: dkim._domainkey.signtelligence.com => pass
TESTING#2: dkim._domainkey.claygarland.com   => pass

DKIM Check
Value
Not Found - Learn how to set up DKIM by clicking here: DKIM Instructions


DMARC Check
Record Syntax:  Passed
DKIM Test:  Failed - DKIM must pass, see you DKIM results above.
SPF Test:   Passed
ADKIM Test: Failed - DMARC Requires that ADKIM or ASPF must pass to be considered valid. Check your Identifier Alignments

ASPF Test:  Passed
RUA Test:   Passed
RUF Test:   Passed
DMARC Passed:   No - Review each component of the DMARC test to determine why.
DMARC Record Location:  Click Here: _dmarc.claygarland.com

DMARC Record:   v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@claygarland.com; ruf=mailto:postmaster@claygarland.com; pct=100
```

As you can see, amavisd seems to think that it should pass on both domains.  On the first domain, everything passes just fine, but on the second domain, it fails as per unlocktheinbox.com.

Comment: Could you post the output from the report you received from unlocktheinbox.com ? At least the DKIM, DMARC and DMARC alignment tests

Comment: Modified original posting as per your request.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I tried to do that, but every time I'd press [enter] it would submit the form.  I even tried pasting from wordpad and it ignored the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Clay,

I looked through the logs on mailtest and I can see that your mail server is not stamping your emails with a domain-key signature. I agree that you have a DKIM record in DNS, but your email's do not contain a signature in the headers.

Henry
www.unlocktheinbox.com